# Meaning of the "hunt his/her own meat" idiom

Tags: idioms

From the description of a theatrical performance:

> At a dinner party in the wilds of New Jersey, two married couples
>   discuss a younger acquaintance–a polyamorous woman who also **hunts her
>   own meat**. Fascinated, they invite this mysterious woman and her two
>   live-in boyfriends to a New Year’s Eve party, which alters the course
>   of their lives.

Is it an idiom and, if so, what is its meaning?

Comment: I think is tied to *polyamorous* instead of *dinner party* if that is what you are wondering.

Comment: I was considering the "polyamorous" and "working woman" meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiom is close... innuendo is more accurate

It would seem the reader is led to believe that "meat" refers to an object of sustenance rather than animal flesh as food.  In this case the context suggests that the system being sustained is one of sexual reproduction rather than a full biological life cycle requiring food to eat.

as you will

Answer (score 1):

It is not really an idiom.  It refers directly to the fact that she actually hunts her local wild game such as deer, turkey, rabbit etc.  (Based on the play "How to Transcend a Happy Marriage")